# How can I declare string reference variable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

The best way to illustrate my question is this C# example:

```
//It seems that the comment is required:
//I need to change the values of someString0, someString1, or someStringN 
//depending on the `type` variable

ref string strKey;

switch(type)
{
    case 0:
        strKey = ref someString0;
        break;
    case 1:
        strKey = ref someString1;
        break;
    //And so on

    default:
        strKey = ref someStringN;
        break;
}

//Set string
strKey = "New Value";
```

Can I do this in C#?

PS. I know that I can do this in a function. I'm asking about an "in-line" approach.

Comment: Strings are reference types already. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to change the values of `someString0`, `someString1`, or `someStringN` depending on the `type` variable to "New Value". I'm not sure how this will work if I remove ref's?

Comment: I think you need an array of strings (or a list).

Comment: Because of immutability, are you _really_ changing the values of the strings...?

Comment: This just sounds like a bad idea. If you gave more context, a means to accomplish what you're really trying to do probably can be recommended that is much more in line with ordinary C# code.

Comment: When you say type are you referring to Data Type or type of your own making?

Comment: While possible in C++, this pattern is not idiomatic C#. It may be possible to do it using `TypedReference` and some undocumented C# keywords, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: OK. Thanks. That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: or, If you know you can do it in a function, you could wrap that code with one that passes all N strings as refs, and set them all in the switch, couldn't you?  why do you *need* to do it "in line"?

Comment: @JohnGardner: It just didn't make sense to me that whatever was available via a function call was not available in-line.

Comment: @ahmd0 that's because you don't *need* the concept of `ref` "in line", because *inside* the method you're free to assign values to whatever you want.  ref is required when you want to make that assignment take effect in the "scope" where the method was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do the assignment similar to the way you're asking for, here is one way that doesn't use ref

```
Action<string> action;
switch (type) {
    case 0:
        action = newVal => someString0 = newVal;
        break;
    case 1:
        action = newVal => someString1 = newVal;
        break;
    case 2:
        action = newVal => someString2 = newVal;
        break;
    default:
        action = null;
        break;
}
if (action != null) action.Invoke("some new value");
```

Performance-wise, the above takes about 8 nanoseconds longer to execute than the direct alternative below

```
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        someString0 = "some new value";
        break;
     case 1:
        someString1 = "some new value";
        break;
      case 2:
        someString2 = "some new value";
        break;
      default:
        break;
}
```

But you're talking a little longer than next to nothing. On my not particularly fast laptop, the Action version takes around 13 nanoseconds to execute vs. the direct assignment method that takes around 5.5 nanoseconds. Neither is likely to be a bottleneck that matters.

Comment: Pretty sure you have to set the action to null to avoid a "use of uninitialized local variable" compile time error.

Comment: every case (including default) sets action, so that should be good to go as is, shouldn't it?

Comment: every case is covered in the switch (the default catches anything not explicitly cased), so action will always have a value assigned. I tested this, so it does work as posted.

Comment: I didn't think the compiler was smart enough for that, but I guess I'm wrong if you tested it.

Comment: @hatchet: Very nice. That is exactly what I needed. Just curious. From the standpoint of the computational involvement, how "expensive" are those `actions`?

Answer (score 1):

why are you splitting this up into a switch and then an assignment later?  why not just set the value in the switch and avoid the ref behavior at all?

```
string newValue = "new value";

switch(type)
{
    case 0:
        someString0 = newValue;
        break;
    case 1:
        someString1 = newValue;
        break;
    //And so on

    default:
        someStringN = newValue;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but obviously my actual example is not that simple. `strKey = "New Value"` is not just a line of code.

Comment: um, yes, it is.  It is the *definition* of a line of code.  all 3 answers so far do the same thing as yours, so you need to show us exactly what you're trying to do.  As you said you want to change the value of a different string depending on the value of a variable.  this (and the other answers) *do exactly that*.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the correct string variable like this:

```
switch(type)
{
    case 0:
        someString0 = "New Value";
        break;
    case 1:
        someString1 = "New Value";
        break;
    //And so on

    default:
        someStringN = "New Value";
        break;
}
```

An even better approach is to replace your n string variables with an array of strings so that the assignment becomes a single line of code:

```
string[] someString;
someString[type] = "New Value";
```

Comment: Your answer is a spitting image of the one above.

Comment: Yes, but independently written, I should clarify. I prefer the array approach anyway, which isn't in the answer above.

Comment: not *exactly* the same as mine, but pretty close.  he has the array version, which is at least historical java/c# way of simulating ref